# counting zeros of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following question : If $f(z,w)=z^2-w^m$ and $g(z,w)=z^2-w^n$, then $O_2/(f)\cong O_2/(g)$ iff $n=m$. $O_2$ is the ring of all holomorphic functions about zero. 
 One way is trivial, for the other way I defined a map $\varphi: O_2\longrightarrow O_2$ which maps $(f)$ into $(g)$, and I found that :
 $(\varphi(z))^2-(\varphi(w))^m= \delta g(z,w)$ for some unit $\delta\in O_2$. Also by the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem , we have that $\varphi(z)= \alpha .h_1, \varphi(w)=\beta.h_2$, where both $ h_1,h_2$ are Weierstrass polynomials, and $\alpha, \beta$ are units in $O_2$.  
Now I want to prove that this leads to a contradiction somehow if $m\neq n$. I know that $(0,0)$ is a zero of order 2 for both $f,g$, how can I use this fact now ?? 
Thank you.

Comment: What is $O_2$? ${}$

Comment: $O_2$ is just the ring of holomorphic functions about zero, I'll edit the question

Comment: What does «holomorphic functions about zero» mean?